# How do I check an object property value that the value is a string with a space

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, object

I feel like this should be straight forward but I can not find anything on this. I have an array of objects and I want to filter it based off of their values.

```
let arr = [
  {
    name : "Justin",
    location : "This place"
  },
  {
    name : "Steve",
    location : "That place"
  }
]
```

This works and returns the object with the name Justin

```
arr.filter(x => x.name == "Justin");
```

However when I run this all I get back is an empty array

```
arr.filter(x => x.location == "This place");
```

It seems to only happen when my string has a space in it.

```js
let arr = [
  {
    name : "Justin",
    location : "This place"
  },
  {
    name : "Steve",
    location : "That place"
  }
]
console.log(arr.filter(x => x.name == "Justin"));
console.log(arr.filter(x => x.location == "This place"));
```

Comment: actually it works, see above.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code on my browser's console and its working fine.

Comment: I can not reproduce.

Comment: Well that's annoying. Because my actual code still is not working. Although I am able to run what I wrote here and have it work...

Comment: I just ran my real code
    classData[0].location;
which returned the correct value. So I copied it verbatim and this didnt work
    classData[0].location == "East Lyme";

Comment: I can get the comparison to work if I directly assign the value of classData[0].location to a variable and do the comparison. If however I make a variable that contains the value of the string at classData[0].location it no longer works.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was never with my filter after all. The CSV file that I had built all my objects off of had put an extra set of quotations around my strings... So instead of "East Lyme" the value was ""East Lyme"".